# Как подключить Spring MVC к heroku postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, spring-boot, heroku

Как подключить Spring приложение к postgresql без deploy на сервер.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://url_data_base_pute.amazonaws.com:5432/DB


spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
```

Зависимости

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>r2dbc-postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Модель и репо

```
@Entity
public class UserModeler {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

  ....
}
public interface UserRepos extends JpaRepository<UserModeler,Long> {
}
```

Ошибка

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a ConnectionFactory: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded database could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable R2DBC Connection URL


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```